# Create a Certificate Signing Request in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a app in Android which communicates with a server that Signs a certificate Signing Request and returns the signed certificate so that I can be used by the client in further calls.

Recently we are trying to move to Flutter (Dart) and I'm trying to replicate the creation of the CSR, but I'm a little lost since I'm relatively new with Dart.

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Here's what the function that creates the CSR looks like:

```
public String createPKI(String mdnString) {
        try {

            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
            //KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");

            ECGenParameterSpec ecGenSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("prime256v1");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecGenSpec, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair kp =  keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            publicKey = kp.getPublic();
            privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
            
            PKCS10CertificationRequest kpGen = new PKCS10CertificationRequest("SHA256withECDSA", new X509Name(String.format("UID=%s", mdnString)), publicKey, null, privateKey); //mdnString is a phone number including the international code.

            String certRequest = Base64.encodeToString(kpGen.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            certRequest = certRequest.replace("\n", "");

            return certRequest;
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if (Constants.DEBUG) {
                Log.v("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The string that I get from this function is sent to the server so it can be signed and then the cert is returned in the response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the basic utils package: https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils.

It contains several utility classes, including `X509Utils` and `CryptoUtils`, which you can use to generate your keypair and CSR. The snippet below should provide some reference:

```dart
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

...

const Map<String, String> X509_SUBJECT = {
    'CN': '...',
    'C': '...',
    'ST': '...',
    'L': '...',
    'O': '...',
    'OU': '...',
  };

AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair = CryptoUtils.generateEcKeyPair();
X509Utils.generateRsaCsrPem(X509_SUBJECT, keypair.privateKey, keypair.publicKey);
```

Comment: The IDE flags the last line: The Argument 'PrivateKey' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RSAPrivateKey'

Comment: I had to cast those parameters as `RSAPrivateKey` and `RSAPublicKey` to get it to work